# Degree 1 maps from $S^1 \times S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose that $M$ is a closed connected 3-manifold and there is a degree 1 map $f: S^1 \times S^2 \to M$.  Does it follow that $M \cong S^1 \times S^2$?  I know that $\pi_1 M$ is cyclic since $f$ must be surjective on $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily. There is a degree one map $S^1 \times S^2 \to S^3$ given by collapsing the $2$-skeleton to a point. Or alternatively, you can construct a degree one map to $S^3$ in [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452916/map-of-arbitrary-degree-from-compact-oriented-manifold-into-sphere?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

An addendum to Goa'uld's answer: If $M$ is a closed oriented connected 3-manifold which admits a degree 1 map $S^2\times S^1\to M$, then either $M$ is $S^3$ or $M=S^2\times S^1$. See [this paper](http://msp.org/pjm/1996/176-1/pjm-v176-n1-p03-s.pdf) where it is proven that nontrivial lens spaces cannot be targets of degree 1 maps from $S^2\times S^1$.

Comment: Thank you for this paper - very helpful!